# Why does the for-loop break when iterating through a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, xcode8, swift2

What I'm trying to do is create an editable calendar made up of arrays.

First I create some variables:

```
import UIKit

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Variables

var userName = "String"
var bedTime: Int = 0
var wakeTime: Int = 7
var sleepMonth = "String"
var quantifiedMonth: Int = 1
```

then a calendar via multidimensional arrays:

```
var day0: [Int] = [0]
var day1: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
var day2: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
var day3: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
var day4: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

var month0 = [[0]]
var january = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var february = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var march = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var april = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var may = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var june = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var july = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var august = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var september = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var october = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var november = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var december = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]

var calendar = [month0, january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, december]
```

Then I try to use nested for-loops to allow the user to say when they are usually asleep:

```
   @IBAction func setVariablesButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        bedTime = Int(bedTimeTextField.text!)!
        wakeTime = Int(wakeTimeTextField.text!)!
        quantifiedMonth = Int(monthToEditTextField.text!)!
        var hourX = bedTime
        var hourZ = wakeTime
        var dayX = 1
        let dayZ = 1
        let lengthMonth = calendar[quantifiedMonth].count

        for _ in 1...lengthMonth // Do the following for as many days
            // as are in the month
        {
            for _ in calendar[1][dayX][hourX]...calendar[1][dayX][24]
            {
                calendar[1][dayX][hourX] = 0 // Loops by amount
                hourX = hourX + 1            // specified 2 lines above
            }

            for _ in calendar[1][dayZ][0]...calendar[1][dayZ][hourZ]
            {
                calendar[1][dayX][hourZ] = 0
                hourZ = hourZ - 1
            }

            dayX = dayX + 1 // Loops by amount specified 8 lines above
        }


        bedTimeLabel.text = "\(calendar[1][1])"
    }
```

When I was building, I always had

```
var quantifiedMonth
```

set to 0, which allowed the program to work. Then I realized that if I set it to 1, then it breaks. I can't wrap my head around why, because of the output that I got when the program worked.

Say I had

```
var quantifiedMonth = 0
bedTime = 20
wakeTime = 7
```

then my output would be

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but when

```
var quantifiedMonth = 1
```

the program crashes. I can't wrap my head around why that is. To my mind, I shouldn't be able to get the output I do when

```
var quantifiedMonth = 0
```

Please help. I tried to be thorough in my question, but if I'm being vague about something, please let me know.

[This is one of the error messages I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GyBH.png)

[Here's another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAMNf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring variables outside of the for-loop that should be declared inside of it.

```
        var hourX = bedTime
        var hourZ = wakeTime
```

should be declared like so:

```
    for _ in 1...lengthMonth 
    {
        var hourX = bedTime
        var hourZ = wakeTime
```

otherwise those variables aren't being set like they should be.

You also need to change lengthMonth to

```
let lengthMonth = calendar[quantifiedMonth].count - 1
```

since you start the for-loop at 1, when your array starts at 0. Otherwise you'll get an "Index out of range" error.